# ¿Cómo se dice "to youtube" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, gramática, jerga-internet

> Voy a youtubear a ver una película filipina.

¿Cómo se dice `to youtube` en castellano?

Comment: perder el tiempo. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En español no es tan fácil convertir sustantivos en  verbos a diferencia del inglés. La traducción directa así como la quieres sería:

> *Youtubear*: Voy a *youtubear* una película filipina.

Pero eso no tiene sentido, podrías intentar decir:

> Voy a ver una película filipina en youtube.
>
> o
>
> Voy a estar en youtube viendo una película filipina.

Answer (score 13):

En castellano no hay generalmente ningún verbo para indicar ver algo en Youtube. Normalmente, se suele traducir como:

> Voy a ver en Youtube una película filipina.

En otros casos, sí se usan anglicismos, como retuitear (Twitter).

Comment: Similar a `tuitear`, opino que `youtubear` estaría más relacionado con publicar un video en esa plataforma, más que al hecho de ver un video...

Answer (score 2):

[Una famosa tirilla de *Calvin & Hobbes*](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25) nos dice: "verbing weirds language" ("el verbear rarea la lengua"): el usar como verbos palabras que no lo son hace parecer rara la la lengua.  Pero en realidad eso es falso en inglés y cierto en español, ya que es una construcción muy común en la una lengua pero no la otra.

Posiblemente un factor de relevancia es que en inglés (y las otras lengua germánicas) es más común que los verbos expresen la *manera* en que se lleva a cabo una acción, mientras que en las lenguas románicas es menos común.  Los ejemplos clásicos se refieren al modo que se expresa la *manera* y la *dirección* del movimiento en ambas familias:

- Mary ran out.

  - Calcado al español: "María corrió hacia/hasta afuera."
- María salió corriendo.

  - Calcado al inglés: "Mary exited by running."

En una oración como *Voy a "youtubear" una película filipina*, se puede notar que el verbo intenta expresar la manera en que vemos la película. Cosa menos común en español que en inglés.

---

Vale notar marginalmente que *María corrió hacia/hasta afuera* no capta el sentido preciso de *Mary ran out*, que igual como *María salió corriendo* implica que no se detuvo antes de llegar afuera, y que posiblemente continuó corriendo después de salir.  En algunos dialectos españoles sin embargo hay *María corrió para afuera* (o más popularmente *corrió pa' fuera*) con el sentido preciso.

También vale notar que *María salió corriendo* es una oración ambigua con dos sentidos—*salió* puede referirse a un verdadero movimiento de salir de un espacio, o puede tener un sentido puramente [aspectual](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspecto_gramatical).  En el ejemplo arriba el sentido al que me refiero es el primero.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube en español sería "ver televisión". Y Youtuber en español sería "Youtubero" o "Conductor de televisión", que sería el término más adecuado en español.